# Compiling a Netbeans project from the command line

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am currently trying to compile my project that I created with Netbeans. When I compile the project with ant from a computer where I already opened the project in Netbeans everything works out fine, however if I do the same on a different computer, it does not seem to recognize the libraries I have used and I get a NoClassDefFound error when I try to run the jar file that was created. If i than again open the project in Netbeans

Does Netbeans set any variables or anything like that on opening the project that are needed to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans installs Ant with some custom ant tasks. Even if on the same computer, if you use a different java/ant installation than what is provided by Netbeans you may run into problems.

That is exactly what happened on the other computer: You have a java/ant installation that knows nothing about Netbeans.